# Issue with accessing web api from mobile app on cellular data

Tags: nginx, httprequest

I'm writing with the hope someone had similar issues and can provide me with an advice.

I have a website hosted on a Linode behind an nginx proxy and a mobile app (made in Flutter) that communicates with the website through http requests.

3 days ago I started receiving reports from users that they cannot use the mobile app and they are getting timeout errors when using the app on cellular data. Nothing changed in the mobile app or the web server.

Of course I cannot reproduce the issue on my local devices. I'm stuck and I have no idea what to do and how to fix this issue.

Only users using Vodafone as their mobile carrier reported this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed by itself the same way it appeared.

Users that reported they cannot use the mobile app for 3 days, now report that the apps works again.

I have no idea what happened but what I will do in the future to at least gain some insight on what's happening when this type of problem occurs again, is to implement an in app logging, that logs locally and then the user can share those logs with me.